# Exception thrown. Add onError handling

Tags: android, rx-java

I've already added onErrorReturn and doOnError, but I still get fatal error. Here's my code:

```
 apiInterface.submitDataToAnalyze("dataToAnalyze", HelperFunctions.authenticationData, 1, uuid, dataToAnalyze.toString(), todayDate)
                                .onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, BasicResponse>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public BasicResponse call(Throwable throwable) {
                                        Log.e(FILE_NAME, "submitDataToAnalyze throwable??");
                                        Log.e(FILE_NAME, throwable.getMessage().toString());
                                        return null;
                                    }
                                })
                                .flatMap(new Func1<BasicResponse, Observable<LocationSuggestion>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Observable<LocationSuggestion> call(BasicResponse basicResponse) {
                                        Log.v(FILE_NAME, "basicResponse: " + basicResponse.toString());
                                        if (basicResponse.getResult() == 1) {
                                            //update TABLE_REQUEST_SUGGESTIONS with serverResponse = 1
                                            dbc.updateRequestSuggestionLog(strTodayDate, strDataToAnalyze, basicResponse.getResult());
                                            return apiInterface.getSuggestion("getSuggestion", HelperFunctions.authenticationData, HelperFunctions.requestVersion, uuid,
                                                    strLocationLat, strLocationLng, radius, requestForDate);
                                        } else {
                                            return Observable.just(null);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(Throwable t) {
                                Log.e(FILE_NAME, "masuk doOnError??");
                                Log.e(FILE_NAME, t.getMessage().toString());
                            }


                        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe();

                }
```

Specifically, here's the error message:

```
E/ISRS: masuk doOnError??
E/ISRS: masuk 22??
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:60)
```

Additional information: the fatal error would occur if submitDataToAnalyze() has problem connecting to my server due to bad connection etc

Comment: I don't think that returing `null` in the `onErrorReturn`is a good idea, especially if you use that value in the `flatMap` without making any check.

Comment: @RiccardoCiovati in that case, what should I return there?

Comment: It should be fine to return `null` but you should check it in the `flatMap`. However I'm not sure it's right to do that, moreover I think you should just remove the `onErrorReturn` at all because it's useless there. Note that `doOnError` doesn't actually catch the exception. If you want to catch it you should pass the proper callback in the `subscribe` method.

Comment: Ouh so what actually the onErrorReturn and doOnError there do? Btw sorry I missed an important info - that is, the error will be thrown when submitDataToAnalyze() failed to connect to my server (due to bad connection etc)

Comment: `onErrorReturn` is useful when, in case of an error, you don't want to break the call chain e provide a value that the next call (in your case the `flatMap`) could use to perform its job. As far as I can see in your code, if `submitDataToAnalyze` fails you don't want to perform the code in the `.flatMap` so for that reason I'm saying that you could remove the `onErrorReturn`. `doOnError`is a hook to have notification that an exception occurred but if you want to catch it you need a proper subscriber.

Comment: Here is my newbie response on a duplicate question : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655840/how-to-properly-handle-onerror-inside-rxjava-android/38017291#38017291

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `onErrorReturn` method you return null, and then this null is propagated further along the chain. So it causes NPE (eg `basicResponse.toString()`). In this case `doOnError` is invocated, but your subscriber still get Throwable, that stays unhandled.

So you have to pass `Subscriber` instance with `onError` implementation.

Another option: in your chain you can use something like `onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())`, so it'll emit nothing and then complete. In this case you are have not to pass Subscriber implementation to `subscribe`.

Comment: Ok.. understood..I think :p. Anyway in my case here, I think onErrorResumeNext suites me better.. but could you show me how to add it inside my code above? I changed onErrorReturn() to .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()) but all I got was "Cannot resolve method 'onErrorResumeNext(rx.Observable<java.lang.Object>)'

Comment: `onErrorResumeNext` takes Func1<java.lang.Throwable,? extends Observable<? extends T> as parameter, so you have to write something like `onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.empty())` (expand lambda if you use java 6/7). Here you can read much more about error handling in RxJava, and there's javadoc about all of methods: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators