# Handling RxJava onErrorReturn and OnErrorNotImplementedException

Tags: android, kotlin, error-handling, rx-java

So i'm trying to implement MVI pattern in android with RxJava, but i want to handle the thrown `error` in a state, together with success and loading, is there anyway to handle the error not from `subscribe(onError = xxx)`

PROCESS

```kotlin
sealed class AuthResult : MviResult {
    sealed class LoadUserResult : AuthResult() {
        object Loading : LoadUserResult()
        data class Success(val user: User) : LoadUserResult()
        data class Fail(val error: Throwable) : LoadUserResult()
    }
}

private val loadUser =
    ObservableTransformer<LoadUserAction, LoadUserResult> { actions ->
        actions.flatMap {
            userManager.getCurrentUser()
                .map<LoadUserResult> { LoadUserResult.Success(it) }
                .onErrorReturn(LoadUserResult::Fail) // HERE? // EDIT FOR THE ANSWER: REMOVE THIS
                .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
                .startWith(LoadUserResult.Loading)
        }.onErrorReturn(LoadUserResult::Fail) // ANSWER: ADD THIS TO CATCH API ERROR
    }

var actionProcess =
    ObservableTransformer<AuthAction, AuthResult> { actions ->
        actions.publish { s->
            Observable.merge(
                s.ofType(LoadUserAction::class.java).compose(loadUser),
                s.ofType(SignInWithGoogleAction::class.java).compose(signInWithGoogle)
            )
        }
    }
```

VIEWMODEL

```kotlin
fun combine(): Observable<AuthViewState> {
    return _intents
        .map(this::actionFromIntent)
        .compose(actionProcess)
        .scan(AuthViewState.idle(), reducer)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .replay(1)
        .autoConnect(0)
}
```

FRAGMENT

```kotlin
disposable.add(viewModel.combine().subscribe(this::response))

private fun response(state: AuthViewState) {
    val user = state.user

    if (user.uid.isBlank() && user.email.isBlank() && user.username.isBlank()) {
        Timber.i("user: $user")
    } else {
        Timber.i("user: $user")
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Will navigate to MainActivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    }

    // HANDLE THE ERROR HERE?
    if (state.error != null) {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error fetching user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        Timber.e("Error loading user ${state.error.localizedMessage}")
    }
}
```

THE ERROR i got was

```kotlin
2020-06-03 22:42:15.073 25060-25060/com.xxx W/System.err: io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling | com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:
```

Comment: What I do is that I handle it in the view model and according to it is success or error I post it to the view the result

Comment: for example do the "observeOn" and "subscribeOn" in in the repository and the rest in viewModel

Comment: see this post, i hope it's be useful . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655840/how-to-properly-handle-onerror-inside-rxjava-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're receiving here is due to you calling `.subscribe()` in your `Fragment`. That variant of the `.subscribe()` (the one that accepts only one parameter -- the `onNext` consumer callback) will only notify the consumer when the stream successfully emits an item (in this case, `AuthViewState`). However, when you observable stream encounters an error, RxJava doesn't have a good way to handle it, since an error callback was not provided in `.subscribe()`. Therefore, it throws the error you've encountered above.

NOTE: RxJava has many overloads of `Observable.subscribe()`, some of which accept a consumer callback for error handling.

However, if your goal is to have the `Observable` always successfully emit an `AuthViewState`, even if an error was encountered, you could make use of `Observable.onErrorReturn()` (or a similar error handling function provided by RxJava). An example usage of that would be:

```kotlin
sealed class ViewState {

    object Loading : ViewState()
    data class Success(val username: String) : ViewState()
    data class Error(val error: Throwable) : ViewState()
}

class UserProfileViewModel(
    private val userService: UserService
) {

    fun getViewState(): Observable<ViewState> {

        return Observable
            .merge(
                Observable.just(ViewState.Loading),
                userService
                    .getUserFromApi()
                    .map { user -> ViewState.Success(user.username) }
            )
            .onErrorReturn { error -> ViewState.Error(error) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, got it now, instead of chaining it with `map` i chain it with `flatMap` to catch the api error, thanks!